# Erro Assinatura

Tags: certificado-digital, web-service

bom dia,
Estou enfrentando um problema ao assinar eventos do REINF.
Porém o erro creio que está mais voltado ao certificado do que ao REINF em si.

Acontece que quando utilizo um determinado certificado, a tag da assinatura (SignatureValue) está sendo computada com 128 bytes, quando na verdade necessito que seja computada com 256 bytes, e isso dá erro de assinatura.

Os outros certificados que estamos utilizando estão todos OK, gerando a SignatureValue com 256 bytes.

Vejam abaixo um debug com o certificado que dá erros de assinatura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E agora um outro certificado que gera a chave corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha grande dúvida é: quem determina o tamanho da assinatura (128 ou 256) é o certificado? Tenho que falar com a empresa que vendeu o certificado para me enviar um outro?

Agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Obrigado.

Comment: Rode a linha de comando `inetcpl.cpl`, para abrir o diálogo *Propriedades da Internet*, vá na aba *Conteúdo* e clique no botão *Certificados*, dê um duplo-clique nesse certificado problemático, vá na aba *Detalhes*. Qual o algoritmo de assinatura do certificado?

Comment: Pedro, obrigado pela resposta: o Algoritmo é sha256RSA, o engraçado é que os outros certificados que estou usando e não dão problema também tem este mesmo algoritmo.